# Instantiate a class with its type

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I'm looking for a way faster than `Activator.CreateInstance` to instantiate a class from its type.

I'm doing it this way for now: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(LoginView));` but it's extremly slow: I see some lags while instantiating different views.

A suggestion for me ? 
I'm googling it for hours now and I did not find out an faster way than this to doing what I want.. :/

Thanks a lot (:

Comment: `new LoginView()` should work. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Cached a compiled delegate that calls the ctor.

Comment: I suppose `typeof(LoginView)` is not the actual argument, or else you could just have written `new LoginView()`, as Cédric suggests. But in any case, are you sure that lag is coming from the reflection layer and not from the `LoginView` constructor itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "extremely slow"? I don't think that the problem is with Activator.CreateInstance - how many times it is called and how long it takes?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yup i receive a `Type` containing the result of typeof(...) :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it's faster by using `new LoginView()` so I guess it's not only the ctor ..

Comment: The generic `new T()` is just again reflection (for reference type). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708459/given-where-t-new-does-new-t-use-activator-createinstance-internally. You need to go the expression route, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6582259/661933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use generics.

```
T MyActivator<T>() where T : new() { return new T(); }

T MyActivator<T>(T variable) where T : new() { return new T(); }
```

The first one is used if you know the  type (explicitly use the type).
The second one is used to infer the type from a variable:

```
MyType blah = MyActivator<MyType>();

SomeType someVar;
object blah = MyActivator(someVar);
```

Comment: If he receives a Type containing the result of typeof, as he says in  his comment, this wont work.

Comment: -1, `new T()` is just again reflection (for reference type). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708459/given-where-t-new-does-new-t-use-activator-createinstance-internally. You need to go the expression route, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6582259/661933

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq Expressions as explained in this [blog post](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/). In your case, it would be

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(LoginView).GetConstructors().First();
ObjectActivator<LoginView> createdActivator = GetActivator<LoginView>(ctor);


LoginView instance = createdActivator();
```

In case the link goes down, this is `ObjectActivator` delegate

```
delegate T ObjectActivator<T>(params object[] args);
```

and the `GetActivator` method

```
public static ObjectActivator<T> GetActivator<T>
    (ConstructorInfo ctor)
{
    Type type = ctor.DeclaringType;
    ParameterInfo[] paramsInfo = ctor.GetParameters();                  

    //create a single param of type object[]
    ParameterExpression param =
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");

    Expression[] argsExp =
        new Expression[paramsInfo.Length];            

    //pick each arg from the params array 
    //and create a typed expression of them
    for (int i = 0; i < paramsInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        Expression index = Expression.Constant(i);
        Type paramType = paramsInfo[i].ParameterType;              

        Expression paramAccessorExp =
            Expression.ArrayIndex(param, index);              

        Expression paramCastExp =
            Expression.Convert (paramAccessorExp, paramType);              

        argsExp[i] = paramCastExp;
    }                  

    //make a NewExpression that calls the
    //ctor with the args we just created
    NewExpression newExp = Expression.New(ctor,argsExp);                  

    //create a lambda with the New
    //Expression as body and our param object[] as arg
    LambdaExpression lambda =
        Expression.Lambda(typeof(ObjectActivator<T>), newExp, param);              

    //compile it
    ObjectActivator<T> compiled = (ObjectActivator<T>)lambda.Compile();
    return compiled;
}
```

One advantage to using this method over the generic method is that you can easily pass in parameters to your constructor but the disadvantage being more verbose code.

Comment: That's a cool one, but i don't need to pass parameters, so i'll keep Yohai's code which is less verbose :P Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @dotixx - No problem, use what's best for you :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** It appears the type is generic, and not just LoginView. You could try this:

```
public void Foo<T>(T input) where T : new()
{
    var myInstance = new T();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking a `Type` that returns the result of `typeof`, take a delegate that gets you an instance of the object:

```
Func<object> myActivator = () => new LoginView();
```

Maybe even have a method to help you do that, if it'd make it easier on your code:

```
public static Func<object> GetActivator<T>() where T : new()
{
    return () => new T();
}
```

This will have a very small overhead for calling the `Func` delegate. Should be much faster than calling `Activator.CreateInstance` on a `Type`.