# Code Refactoring by applying design pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have to write 3 functions which accepts a parameter of BaseClass type and then return a   DerivedClasses as the return value.

```
Public DerivedClass1 SimpleTest1(BaseClass baseType)
{
DerivedClass1 derivedClass1 = new DerivedClass1();
derivedClass1.item = baseType.item;
derivedClass1.itemGroup = baseType.itemGroup;
return derivedClass1;
}

Public DerivedClass2 SimpleTest2(BaseClass baseType)
{
DerivedClass2 derivedClass2 = new DerivedClass2();
derivedClass2.item = baseType.item;
derivedClass2.itemGroup = baseType.itemGroup;
return derivedClass2;
}

Public DerivedClass3 SimpleTest3(BaseClass baseType)
{
DerivedClass3 derivedClass3 = new DerivedClass3();
derivedClass3.item = baseType.item;
derivedClass3.itemGroup = baseType.itemGroup;
return derivedClass3;
}
```

The code written in all the 3 methods is the same! Is there a better way to achieve this, without code duplication? Is there a specific design pattern that I can apply here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use generics on this and you can express it fairly nicely:

```
public T SimpleTest<T>(BaseClass baseType) where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    T derived = new T();
    derived.item = baseType.item;
    derived.itemGroup = baseType.itemGroup;
    return derived;
}
```

There is one caveat that you *have* to have a default constructor or else this won't work. In instances where you have a constructor with one or more arguments (but the same signature for each), you can dynamically instantiate the class using Reflection, as in dbaseman's answer.

Comment: Interesting.  Any thoughts of pro, con of using new T() vs dbaseman's use of Activator.CreateInstance() ?

Comment: @dreza: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1649108/312124) answer, there is none.

Comment: I think its better to have a where new() as it says something about what kind of type can be used.

Comment: I'd also simplfy it down to  public T SimpleTest<T>(BaseClass baseType) where T:BaseClass, new()
        {
            return new T {Item = baseType.Item, ItemGroup = baseType.ItemGroup};
        }

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good application of [generic functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ...

```
public T SimpleTest<T>(BaseClass baseType) where T : BaseClass
{
    T derivedClass = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    derivedClass.item = baseType.item;
    derivedClass.itemGroup = baseType.itemGroup;
    return derivedClass
}
```