# C# place a TYPE into a variable and use it instead of type at declaration of new variables

Tags: c#, variables, types

I searched on the site for an answer that I needed, but I could not find it...

I have this:

```
string sNameOfClass="BusNode";
```

And the class already exists, and has its own properties.

Now I need to do something like this, but I dont know how...

```
sNameOfClass variable1 = new sNameOfClass()
```

and use `varible1` forward in program as a normal variable...

so like

```
coorinateClass cs = new ks();
cs.a=11;
cs.b=33;
cs.c=55;
```

Any clues?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What *actual problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: You need to put actual code in the question, with actual code formatting....

Comment: seems like he has a typename in  a string and wants to create an instance of the class the type refers to

Comment: i have a list of classNames...witch has more then 1000 classes....and now i need to access all of them like that,...

Comment: How do you know what you're supposed to do with each of those "classes"?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage a class with its name you can use this:

```
//your class name
string sNameOfClass = "YourNameSpace.BusNode";
//create type class from your class name
Type T = Type.GetType(sNameOfClass);
//create new instance of class
var NewInstanse = Activator.CreateInstance(T);
//set property 
T.GetProperty("a").SetValue(NewInstanse, 11);
//get value of property
var a = T.GetProperty("a").GetValue(NewInstanse);
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.   ---- error at line var NewInstanse = Activator.CreateInstance(T);

Comment: i see    Type T = Type.GetType(sNameOfClass); is null,

Comment: i see the problem, it does not recognises the namespace for that class... but that is my problem...thx bro u helped me a lot....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance` Method

Check out this link : [Activator.CreateInstance Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string sNameOfClass="BusNode";

switch (sNameOfClass)
{
 case "BusNode":
       BusNode variable1 = new BusNode()
       break;
 case "...."
       break;
}
```

Comment: Above code is useful for small number of classes....Please check once "CreateInstance vs new" 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649066/activator-createinstancet-vs-new